# Is "agriculture" a verb?

Tags: verbs, word-usage

Can I say *to agriculture the land*? If not, what would the alternative be?

Comment: 1) No. 2) Cultivate.

Comment: You could _[farm](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/farm)_ it.

Comment: agriculturate? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not. What you do to the land to make it productive is *cultivate* it.

Comment: Didn't see JR's comment before posting.

Comment: @Jasper: I was just relieved that my answer agreed with Barrie's!

Comment: How about *sow, plant, or till*?

Comment: @Noah: They are hyponyms of 'cultivate'.

Answer (score -2):

You can't agriculture a land.

You could, however, *farm* / *cultivate* / *improve* / *nurse* / *patronize* / *refine* / *rear* / *devote oneself to* the land.

I used synonyms... soo...

Comment: Are you sure about *patronize*, *rear*, and (to a lesser extent), *nurse*? (Those may by synonyms with *cultivate*, but I'm not sure I'd apply those verbs to agricultural land.) It's always good to make sure synonyms are indeed synonyms – in the right sense of the word.

Comment: No, some of those are definitely not appropriate to this sense. -1.